# How to dynamically change scrolling shadows?

Tags: javascript, scroll, shadow

How to dynamically change level of the shadow opacity under fixed header while scrolling down?

I found many solutions of how to add a shadow instantly on scroll down. But how to change it step by step, so it appears to fade in slowly.

Here is example - [Dynamic shadow](http://thisisluckyme.com/) 
As you can see if you scroll down with a tiny steps the shadow will appear slowly.
I think they are changing opacity level. 
And I found that Google in account settings uses the same effect with changing opacity level.

I have [my solution](http://codepen.io/alexlime/pen/vDujF), but shadow is appearing instantly so its not what i want to create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is change

```
$('#top-shadow).show();
```

to

```
$("#top-shadow").css({'display':'block', 'opacity':y/10});
```